# Catch OnMouseMove messages for edit control in a window created by createdialog?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, onmousemove

I have a dialog window that is created by [`CreateDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga).

Within the dialog window is a text edit control which is created automatically by the `CreateDialog()` call, however I can't seem to catch `OnMouseMove` messages for it - only its parent window (of the controls, not the dialog).  `CreateDialog()` only allows you to set a procedure function for the main dialog (not the sub objects, like the edit controls) and if I catch the `OnMouseMove` messages there, they only trigger for mouse movement on the main dialog itself (anywhere there is NOT a control, ex. buttons, text edit boxes, etc).

Short of creating the window manually with `CreateWindowEx()` (and all the sub objects), is there a way to catch the `OnMouseMove` messages associated with the specific text edit control by its ID or something? I have its handle retrieved by `GetDlgItem()`.

What I am ultimately trying to accomplish is to both read the text below the mouse cursor and display a relevant tooltip if the word is recognized/matched, and I am definitely open to other alternatives if you have any ideas!

Here is the basic code :

Creation of the dialog, using the `DBG_DLG` template to define the controls

```cpp
hDbg = CreateDialog(hCurInst, TEXT("DBG_DLG"), 0, DbgDlgProc);
```

The `DBG_DLG` template is defined in the project's `.rc` file. I couldn't find a simple way to paste that code here, but it has a particular text edit control that I am trying to catch with an ID of `ID_OP_ED`.

Relevant code from `DbgDlgProc()` that does NOT work, and only catches messages associated with the main dialog and not the controls themselves.  Hovering over the controls causes no messages to be caught by this routine.

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK DbgDlgProc(
                         HWND hwnd,
                         UINT message,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam
                         )
{

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        return TRUE;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        OnMouseMove(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam), (DWORD)wParam);
        return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the HWND of the child text edit (from `GetDlgItem()`), you can subclass it directly, using `SetWindowLongPtr()` or better `SetWindowSubclass()`. Your subclass will receive all of the messages sent directly to the control.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview)